# Display Welcome username to logged in user in php

Tags: php, mysql

This is my index. php

```
<?php

// Inialize session
session_start();
// Check, if username session is NOT set then this page will jump to login page
if (!isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
header('Location: index.html');
}
echo "Welcome", $_SESSION['username'];
?>


<div id="content">
<p><?php
if(isset($_SESSION['username'])){
    echo "Welcome", $_SESSION['username'];}?>
</p> 
</div>
```

This is my check login.php where after i submit details they go here

```
<?php

session_start();
ob_start();-
$host="localhost"; // Host name 
$username=""; // Mysql username 
$password=""; // Mysql password 
$db_name="test"; // Database name 
$tbl_name="members"; // Table name 

// Connect to server and select databse.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

// Define $myusername and $mypassword 
$myusername=$_POST['myusername']; 
$mypassword=$_POST['mypassword']; 

// To protect MySQL injection
$myusername = stripslashes($myusername);
$mypassword = stripslashes($mypassword);
$myusername = mysql_real_escape_string($myusername);
$mypassword = mysql_real_escape_string($mypassword);
$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE username='$myusername' and password='$mypassword'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

// Mysql_num_row is counting table row
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);

// If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row
if($count==1){

// Register $myusername, $mypassword and redirect to file "login_success.php"
$_SESSION['username'] = $username;
$_SESSION['password'] = $password;
header("location:index1.php");
}
else {
echo "Wrong Username or Password";
}
ob_end_flush();
?>
```

I am trying to get the logged in users name to appear after welcome in index.php but it isnt seeming to work for and ive spent hours googling it.

Comment: What specifically doesn't work? Does it say "Welcome " with no username, or does it go to the other page?
Also, don't put your variables in strings for no reason. `"$host"` is pointless. `$host` is fine.

Comment: You defined $username = ""; then $_SESSION['username'] = $username; it's normal you have an empty string no ?

Comment: This isn't it, but you're setting the `session` user name to the `$username` and not `$myusername`.  Also, mysql_* functions are deprecated.  You should use mysqli or PDO, with prepared statements.  Another side note, you should be hashing and salting passwords, not storing in plain text.

Comment: @MichaelBenjamin you can echo with commas. This is faster than concatenating because php must check the datatypes.

Answer (score 0):

```
$_SESSION['username'] =
$username;
$_SESSION['password'] =
$password;
```

You should change this to:

```
$_SESSION['username'] =
$myusername;
$_SESSION['password'] =
$mypassword;
```

Because $myusername and $mypassword refer to the username and password sent to the script from the form data.

Comment: Thank you so much, can not believe i missed that -_-

Comment: I wasn't the only person to mention it, @Matthew Johnson did too.